# Is there any method to know how many rows Resultset contains? Java and MSSQL

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

i want to run a loop (may be a do while) to keep getting reults from MSSQL. i have done the do part of the loop. but can find a method that will stop the loop if no results (rows) are returned from mssql. my code is:

```
String query = "SELECT TOP 1 *  FROM tbl_Url WHERE UrlProcessed = 0";
PreparedStatement preparedquery = con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet results = preparedquery.executeQuery();
```

what method should i use to terminate the loop if no rows are returned.is there any method for the Resultset which returns boolean if any result is returned from mssql or a method which returns number of rows. 0 if no rows returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to know that the ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.

To get the number of rows you can try this:

```
ResultSet results = preparedquery.executeQuery();

if (!results.next() ) {
System.out.println("no data");
}else{
results.last();
int rowCount = results.getRow();
}
```

Comment: yes you're right. but when i use the methods like results.last , results.isLast() or results.first() the driver gives me an exception: `The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets`

Comment: i have added a condition first which actually checks if the results set is not empty. This should avoid any exceptions. I hope it helps!

Comment: Getting the row count can be very expensive either because all rows will need to be processed on the server or because - in addition - all those rows actually need to be sent to the JDBC driver. Using `next()` as the loop condition is the best way when all you want to know is when to stop.

Comment: You are right, the question though has two parts into it. First is knowing if the data set is not empty and if not so how many rows it contains. I am not sure if there are better optimisation to cover both sides of the question fully and be less expensive.

Comment: `if(!results.next())` helped stop the loop

Answer (score 3):

Use **boolean next()**
Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on. 
**When a call to the next method returns false**, the cursor is positioned after the last row.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply trying to find out if there is any rows contained in results within your while loop, and break if there is none, ResultSet.first(); will give you this...

Q. Is there a good reason you're selecting only one row at a time??

```
while(true){
    String query = "Select top 1 * from tbl_Url where UrlProcessed = 0";
    PreparedStatement preparedQuery = con.prepareStatement(query)
    ResultSet results = preparedquery.executeQuery();
    if(!results.first())
        break;
    // process data here...
}
```

Comment: but when i use the methods like results.last , results.isLast() or results.first() the driver gives me an exception: `The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets`

Comment: Saad, what is the code you're running, because from what I know, the ResultSet is always returned with the cursor placed before the first row. So doing a .first()  as the very first operation on the ResultSet will either return true, (ok) or false (no row)... are you trying to move the cursor before you try to see if there's data there??